# Ler array de objetos num json em delphi

Tags: json, delphi

Preciso pegar os valores que estão dentro de um array no JSON. Uma parte deste JSON é:

```
{
"total": 1,
"limit": 50,
"questions": [
    {
        "date_created": "2020-08-20T13:22:01.600-04:00",
        "item_id": "MLB1623490410",
        "seller_id": 419059118,
        "status": "UNANSWERED",
        "text": "Hola, estoy interesado en Item De Prueba, por favor comunícate conmigo. ¡Gracias!",
        "id": 11436370259,
        "deleted_from_listing": false,
        "hold": false,
        "answer": null,
        "from": {
            "id": 419067349
        }
    }
],
```

Consigo pegar os valores de total e limit usando

```
JsonObject.GetValue('total').Value
```

Mas não consigo pegar os valores dentro do question. Como posso fazer?